# Is there a way to make react context read only?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to pass context around to other react components but not allow them to actually adjust the value.

My best guess would be to provide a function that retrieves value in a *getter like way*. Although the user could still adjust the function they would be unable to modify the actual value of the item.

Comment: It's read only by default, any modification made by any child won't change its parents copy

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can make a read-only context, through a read-only provider.

For example (my data is a list of farmers):

```
const FarmersContext = React.createContext();

function FarmersProvider({ children }) {
    const [farmers, setFarmers] = React.useState(null);

    return (
        <FarmersContext.Provider value={farmers}>
            <FarmerFetcher setFarmers={setFarmers} />
            {children}
        </FarmersContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Children of *FarmersProvider* can access data this way:

```
const farmers = React.useContext(FarmersContext)
```

They can only access *farmers*, not *setFarmers*, so this data is read-only.

On the other hand, *FarmerFetcher* can access *setFarmers* through its props, because someone has to fetch the data at some point. But this could be done within *FarmersProvider* if you prefer.